# Haskell Data type 3-address code

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a compiler into an intermediate language, and for that purpose I created the following data types:

```
   data C = Atr Var Var
            deriving(Show)  
    data E = Var Op Var
            deriving (Show)  
    data Var = V String
            | N Int
            deriving (Show)
    data Op = OpPlus
            | OpMinus
            | OpMult
            | OpDiv
            deriving (Show)
```

But I'm having problems when I use the `E` data type, for example:

```
 compileE :: Exp -> Int -> [(String,Int)] ->(Int,Var,[C])
 compileE ( Plus e1 e2 ) k regs = let (v1,t1,l1)= (compileE e1 k regs);
                                            ( v2,t2,l2 ) =( compileE e2 v1 regs);
                                            t = new_Var v2
                                            in (v2+1,V t, l1 ++ l2 ++ [Atr (V t) (t1 OpPlus  t2)])
```

In the expression "`t1 OpPlus t2`", it says `t1` is applied to too many arguments.  That would make sense since `t1` doesn't exist in the data type, but `t1` is a `Var` and that expression should be in the `Var Op Var` form.

Any sugestions on a work around?

EDIT:

Aparently my english sucked and i didn't explain well my question:
My intermediate language needs to be defined using this rule, among others: "E<- Var Op Var" where E is an expression, Var could be an int or string (case of variable) and Op the symbol im using. At the end of the compileE function, im trying to concatenate the previous expressions ( l1 and l2) with the current one to create the [C] list.

My problem is that I'm not being able to add the "Var Op Var" format (t1 OpPlus  t2) because its listing t1 as a function and not as part of the Var data type.

Comment: could you provide a signature for `compileE`?

Comment: compileE :: Exp -> Int -> [(String,Int)] ->(Int,Var,[C]) but im changing as it goes trying to find a solution

Comment: please add it to your question! And try to explain in English what you are trying to get from that function. It seems to me that your function is trying to evaluate the expression, not compile it.

Comment: It's not that your english sucks, it's just that it was too brief *for me* to understand what you want to do.

Comment: Ok, it looks to me that the datatype `E` is meant to be an expression tree, but somehow you've turned into a tree of just two levels (ie. one node containing an op and refs to 2 leaves). perhaps you want to reconsider that definition of `E` to include recursion?

Comment: @didierc Part of the point of three address code is that no statement can refer to more than 3 addresses (variables). If an expression `E` was allowed to be recursive it could refer to any number of variables.  The limitations of intermediate languages are deliberate to make the compiler's job easier.

Comment: Ok, I was confused by the type `Exp`, which isn't specified, and I mixed it up with `E`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data Exp = Plus Exp Exp 
         | Name String
         | Const Int

data C = Atr Var E
       deriving(Show)
data E = E Var Op Var
       deriving (Show)  
data Var = V String
         | N Int
         deriving (Show)
data Op = OpPlus
        | OpMinus
        | OpMult
        | OpDiv
        deriving (Show)


new_Var :: Int -> String
new_Var i = "sym" ++ show i

compileE :: Exp -> Int -> [(String,Int)] ->(Int,Var,[C])

compileE     (Name s) k regs = (k, V s, [])
compileE    (Const i) k regs = (k, N i, [])
compileE (Plus e1 e2) k regs = (v2+1, V t, l1 ++ l2 ++ [Atr (V t) (E t1 OpPlus t2)])
  where (v1,t1,l1) = compileE e1 k regs
        (v2,t2,l2) = compileE e2 v1 regs
        t          = new_Var v2
```

The above passes compilation. I made up an `Exp` type to match more or less what I thought would be the AST `compileE` is expecting. The end result corresponds to the signature of your function. `new_Var` generates symbols for your variables. At this point you probably don't need yet the `regs` variable; it will probably be useful at a later stage, when your compiler does the register allocation phase.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you forgot to give `E` a data constructor of its own.  `data E = Var Op Var` defines `Var` as the data constructor for `E`, and it takes two arguments (one `Op`, one `Var`).  Because `Var` is also the name of a separate type, this is not a good idea.  It seems that you meant to write `E = E' Var Op Var`, where `E'` is some new name (it could even be `E`!), after which (assuming I'm reading your intent correctly) `t1 OpPlus t2` becomes `E' t1 OpPlus t2`.

Note that, even after you fix this, your code still won't work, as it looks like you're trying to use an `E` value as the second argument to `Atr`, even though the second argument should be a `Var`.  What are you really trying to do there?

Comment: Basicly what im trying to wright is: 
  t1 <- 1 + 1 ;
  s1 <- t1

being the <- the atr function, but im not sure anymore if the end result should be "1 OpPlus 1" or "OpPlus 1 1"

Comment: By the way, what the asker forgot is a *data* constructor, not a type constructor. The first `E` in `data E = E Var Op Var` is the type constructor, the second `E` is a data constructor.